# How to select 10 row without full scan

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have select like this:

```
select * from 
     (select aa.*,rownum as rn
   from (select someRows 
          from (select * 
                 from table a 
              left outer join mySecTable b)
       left outer join otherTable c 
      where conditions) aa 
  order by aa.myColumn) ff
where ff.rn >=30 and rn<40
```

I want to select ordered data's 10 column without full scan , but this select is going on full scan and it is no matter what will be in last where condition there will be `ff.rn >=30 and rn<40` or nothing select's time is same.

my main select is

```
select * from
     (select someRows
     from
         (select *
         from myTable a
          left outer join  mySecTable b
    ) left outer join otherTable c 
    where conditions
```

than i want to order this select and take 10 row . How can i do this without full scan ?

Comment: Your goal should not be to eliminate a full scan, it should be for the query to perform as well as possible - it could be that the best way possible is to use a full scan.  It's impossible to say just from looking at your query, but if there were an index on `myColumn` the optimizer *might* use that index to avoid a full scan - but it's also highly likely that it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you are selecting `rownum as rn` at the same level where you are specifying `order by aa.myColumn`. In such case rn will be unordered and query will return you unordered result (as it assign rownum to rows, and after that will order them by myColumn).
You should to either move rownum to upper SQL level (add one more) or move order by to lower SQL level.

If you have index for myColumn, then where condition with this column and < or > that always return true may help
like

```
where myColumn>0 -- for number
```

or

```
where myColumn>chr(0) -- for varchar
```

So SQL should look something like

```
select * from 
     (select aa.*,rownum as rn
   from (select someRows 
          from (select * 
                 from table a 
              left outer join mySecTable b)
       left outer join otherTable c 
      where conditions
        AND myColumn>chr(0)
      order by aa.myColumn) aa 
  WHERE rownum < 40) ff
where ff.rn >=30
```

(I moved order by to lower level SQL, added `myColumn>chr(0)` condition and moved left bound to lower level SQL `rownum<40`)